# How can I center my navbar on different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a page.  This page will have a custom navigation bar.

Nav bar dimensions - width:800px  height:100px.
Body bgcolor: grey; Nav bar bgcolor: blue.

Since the nav bar will be 800px wide and be blue, I would like the nav bar to stay centered on the page but keep stretching blue to the left and right edges of larger screens.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it, the trick is margin-auto left and right

```
.outer
    {
      background-color:Gray;
    }

    .inner
    {
     width:800px;
     height:100px;
    background-color:blue; 
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    }

      <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">blah</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I understand how to center something, however I would like the color to stretch to the left and right of the 800px object to fill the screen width.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Chaddly Switch the blue background color to the .outer wrapping element.

Comment: My example should do it (though i didnt test!) the grey will be 100% across the screen, except for 800px in the middle of the grey will be blue. Thats what you wnated right?

Comment: Just tested in fiddle and it works - as logn as you replace the class selector . for an id # :)

Comment: body{
background-color: grey;
height: 100%;
margin:0px;
}
        
#outer{
background-color:#003366;
height:120px;
}
        
#inner{
width:800px;
height:120px;
color: #ffffff;
background-color:#003366; 
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
<html>
        <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="outer">
         <div id="inner">
          blah
         </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you got the answer you were looking for, but for clarity you can nest and centre your navigation element within a wrapper element that has 100% width and similar styles, as follows.

```
<div id="navWrap">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
#navWrap {
    width:100%;
    background:blue;
}
#nav {
    width:800px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:blue;
}
body {
    background:grey;
}
</style>
```